# Repaint method doesnt work correctly (repainting after timer.stop() )

Tags: java, graphics, repaint

I have a class that extends JPanel like this:

```
public class Renderer extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID=1l;
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    mainClass.mainClass.repaint(g);
}
```

}

then in my mainClass i implements actionPerformed method, after that i created in a class called "Variables"in that class i created a static timer `public static Timer sleep;` and in mainClass constructor i initialize it and start it

```
Variables.sleep = new Timer(20, this);
Variables.sleep.start();
```

so the problem is: When i am using `sleep.stop();` (method in button)  the repaint method stops , but when i am moving the programms window it is start repainting again, after some repaints it stops. After that the programm works correctly (stop and start or restart methods). How to make the repaint method not to repaint while i am moving the programs window.

**What i have done:**

1) created Timer, start and stop it before the initialization, then restart it afte initialization

2) tried to play with JFrame onMove method (`public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0)`)

Comment: I am trying to create an AI Flappy Bird, and i have a separete panel to control what is happening on the screen , for example start- stop buttons to pause the simulation, max number of birds, animation speed and so on. Everything else works great exept the start-stop buttons

Comment: Ok - `paintComponent` is suppose to paint the current state - nothing else. Stopping the action would involve "freezing" the state - then anything that is painted will paint the current (frozen) state - you don't control when something get's paint in Swing, that's the job of the `RepaintManager` and Swing uses a lazy approach to painting - only painting when it thinks it needs to. So, instead of trying to stop the painting process, stop your update process instead